# How do I make my overflow visible without using absolute positioning and z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that contains 3 rows of divs. When I hover over any one of the divs, I want the div to expand downward and cover the div below it. I achieved this using absolute positioning and by increasing the z-index value when the user hovers over the div. I would rather not style each row differently with a unique absolute position, but in order to make one div drape over the one below upon hover, I feel like I have to use this absolute positioning. Is there a more elegant way that I can create a fixed grid of 5-item rows that have expanding divs that overlap each other when the user hovers?

https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/Test_TeamSlideshow.html

```
<script src="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/jquery1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/ProductionPayrollHomeFlexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script defer src="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/flexslider.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/carousel.js"></script> <!--referred to as modernizr.js in the flexslider package-->

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet'>


<script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).load(function() {
              $('#carousel').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                asNavFor: '#slider'
              });

              $('#slider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                sync: "#carousel"
              });
            });

</script>

<style>

    .flex-nav-prev, .flex-nav-next{display: none;}   /*hide the left and right arrows*/


    #BackgroundContainer{
        background-color: white; 
        height: 1180px;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .profile_container{
        height: 163px;
        width: 144px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        background-color: rgba(207, 232, 221, 0.6); /*light green almost transparent*/
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #99D1E0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    }

    .profile_container span{
        display: block;
        width: 123px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Comfortaa' !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .profile_container .employee_name{
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #395880; 
        font-size: 14px !important;
        word-spacing: 120px;
        width: 130px;
    }

    .profile_container .job_title{
        line-height: 17px;
    }

    .pic_container{
        height: 130px;
        width: 124px;
        border-radius: 150px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    }

    .profile_pic{height: 160px;}

    .Team_Container{margin-left: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 0;}
    .Team_Container:hover{z-index: 1;}  

    .Team_Container div:hover{  /*when the user hovers over the profile-containing div*/
        height: 343px; 
        background-color: rgba(176, 196, 222, 0.9) !important; /*purplish blue almost opaque*/
        border-color: #7795BF !important;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 1px grey;
    }   

    .Team_Container div div:hover{height: 160px; background-color: aqua;}   /*when the user hovers over the picture-containing inner div*/

    .Team_Container_Row2{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 193px;
    }

    .Team_Container_Row3{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 373px;
    }

    .flexslider{
        margin-top: 4px;
        border: none !important; /*overrides the flexslider.css file style*/
    }

    .flex-viewport{width: 820px; height: 750px;}
    .flex-active-slide{width: 820px;}

    #slider{
        background: none; 
        margin-bottom: 20px;  /*overrides the flexslider.css file style*/
        min-height: 370px; /*no longer necessary? this reserves height for the slider and makes sure that the blurb at the bottom stays there as the page loads*/
    }

    #carousel{
        height: 40px;
        width: 910px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        background-color: transparent; 
    }

    #carousel li{
        text-align: center;
    }   

    #carousel span{
        font-family: comfortaa;
        color: #165D7A; 
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 37px;
        text-align: center;
    }   

    .department_description_container{
        width: 780px;
        min-height: 90px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: linear-gradient(#DAE0E3, #C1D3DB);
        border: solid 2px #7F9AAD;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        top: 560px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    #department_description{
        font-family: comfortaa;
        color: #304F5E;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

</style>


<div id="BackgroundContainer">

<br>

<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Department1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Department2</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>  

<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <div class="Team_Container" id="team1"> 
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person1 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person2 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container">
            <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person3 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person4 LastName</span> <br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person5 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="Team_Container Team_Container_Row2">    
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person6 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person7 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person8 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person9 LastName</span> <br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person10 LastName</span>    <br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="Team_Container Team_Container_Row3">    
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person11 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person12 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person13 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="department_description_container">
            <span id="department_description">Department 1 does X, Y, and Z.</span> 
        </div>          

    </li>

    <li>

        <div class="Team_Container" id="team1"> 
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person1 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person2 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container">
            <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person3 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person4 LastName</span> <br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container">
                <div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person5 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="Team_Container Team_Container_Row2">    
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person6 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person7 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person8 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person9 LastName</span> <br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_container"><div class="pic_container"></div>
                <span class="employee_name">Person10 LastName</span><br>
                <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
                <span>Department</span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="department_description_container">
            <span id="department_description">Department 2 does U, V, and W.</span> 
        </div>      

    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap all your profiles into one container and use percentages for your widths. By default, elements will automatically break downwards if they do not fit on the same row.

For example, if you have 6 divs and they are all set to width: 20%, the last div will automatically break down onto a separate row.

This way, your elements will be relatively responsive and you wont need to hard code values.

Comment: That's a helpful tip, but I'm not too concerned with the way the elements break downward, I'm more concerned with the the overflow of each div covering the div directly below. Is this kind of overflow possible without using absolute positioning?